# Recording and storing Midi data with arduino and midi shield

Tags: arduino-mega, programming, shields, midi

i need help getting started on writing a sketch that would let me record and store midi data from a midi controller connected to a arduino mega through a midi shield. are there any functions in the midi library that will aid in this task?

Answer (score 2):

The Arduino MIDI Library allows you to read and write MIDI messages, but only in real time.

Storing MIDI data makes sense only with timestamps, so you have to call `millis()` or `micros()` when you receive a message.

How to actually store the data is something that you have to design yourself; which data structure to use depends on what you want to do with the data later.

Comment: once i have the data stored i want to be able to play it back